# Error handling the ldap_initalize in C

Tags: c, error-handling, ldap, pam

**Background**
I am having trouble error handling the `ldap_initialize` function in C.

After reading through numerous documents (most which are just flat out copies of the man pages), I have found a number of ways (which are possibly misleading or wrong) to error handle this function.

Here is the code that I am having trouble with:

```
//--------------------------------------
// declarations
//--------------------------------------
int status = 0;
int optionHandlingStatus = 0;
char * ldapErrorString = NULL;
char serverAddress[PLS_STRING_ARRAY_SIZE];

//--------------------------------------
// prepare the server's address
//--------------------------------------
sprintf(
    serverAddress,
    "ldap://%s:%s",
    settings->serverAddress,
    settings->serverPort
);
//writeDebugLog("LDAP server address set to [%s].", serverAddress);

//--------------------------------------
// connect to the server
//--------------------------------------
status = ldap_initialize(&ldapServerConnection, serverAddress);
optionHandlingStatus = ldap_get_option(ldapServerConnection, LDAP_OPT_RESULT_CODE, &status);
if (status != LDAP_SUCCESS || errno != LDAP_SUCCESS) { //the specs are strange
    if (status && errno) {
        writeDebugLog("CONNECTION Fail!.");
        writeSyslog("CONNECTION Fail!.");
    }
    ldapErrorString = ldap_err2string(status);
    writeDebugLog("Connection to server failed with [%s].", ldapErrorString);
    writeSyslog(
        "LDAP server initalization error. Check [%s] server's status.",
        serverAddress
    );
    return(NULL);
}
```

**Problem**
The documents say that `ldap_initialize` should either:
1. return a NULL pointer in the case of a connection error (if I use `ldap_init`)
2. return an error status that can be fetched using `ldap_get_option`

However, neither of these methods are reliable. I have done thorough testing of the function that I created to start the connection to my LDAP server. There are times `ldap_init` returns with a valid pointer to an LDAP object, `ldap_initialize` returns the with the error code LDAP success (when using `ldap_get_option`), and ldap_get_option returns successfully when parsing error codes.

I have found that if I check C's `errno` variable I can fairly accurately get the connection status of the `ldap_initialize` function as it seems to be setting an errno when it fails (`errno == 2`) => "No such file or directory".

When I specify random unused ports in my program, this is usually accurate. However, I went to test my program more thoroughly with a program named `pamtester` and it was unable to authenticate the users that I had specified. The error that was set was "No such file or directory" immediately after my call to `ldap_initialize`.

I set C's (`errno = 0`) by force after ldap_initialize and I was able to authenticate users against my LDAP database successfully.

**Questions**
1. What is the correct way to error handle the `ldap_initialize` function?
2. Should I be using a different function to initialize my LDAP connection?
3. If error status is actually handled by C's errno flag and not by `ldap_get_options` why do all of the man pages and examples state otherwise?

Comment: Only check `errno` if `ldap_initilize` returned some different then `LDAP_SUCCESS`. Also do this immedialty after `ldap_initilize` returned, otherweise `errno` might have been spoiled. Alternativly save the value of `errno` after ``ldap_initilize` returned.

Comment: I don't know what man pages you've been reading, but the "Errors" section seems fairly clear: http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_initialize

Comment: I have been doing that, however, the problem is there are times that `ldap_initialize` will return `LDAP_SUCCESS` on an invalid connection, but `errno` will be set. The error handling has been constantly conflicting leaving me confused, so I posted here.

Comment: You don't do that at least not in the code you show us.

Comment: `errno` is meaningless unless the function returned a value indicating failure. Library functions do not set errno to 0 if they succeed. Try setting errno to 0 before you call the function and it should still be 0 after if the function returns successfully.

Comment: __If an error occurs, ldap_open() and ldap_init() will return NULL and errno should be set appropriately. ldap_initialize() and ldap_init_fd() will directly return the LDAP code associated to the error (or LDAP_SUCCESS in case of success); errno should be set as well whenever appropriate__ I have read this and followed the directions on this exact site, however, there have been several times that I hand the an invalid server parameter where `ldap_initialize` returns LDAP_SUCCESS, but `errno` is set to `2`. In this situation `errno` was correct, but `ldap_initialize` was not.

Comment: Also, `ldap_get_options` doesn't seem to have anything to do with errors.

Comment: According to [Manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_get_option), if you look at `LDAP_OPT_RESULT_CODE` it appears to be a way to check the status set in the LDAP object when using `ldap_initialize` because `ldap_initialize` does not return a NULL pointer on error. I may be misreading the documents, and I may not fully understand them however.

Comment: `ldap_initialize()` never returns `NULL`, as it returns an `int` and `NULL` is a pointer value. You seem to be mixing up `"ldap_initialize()` and `"ldap_init()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only check `errno` if `ldap_initilize` returned something different then `LDAP_SUCCESS`. Also do this immedialty after `ldap_initilize` returned, otherweise `errno` might have been spoiled.

The code shall look like this:

```
int status = ldap_initialize(&ldapServerConnection, serverAddress);
if (status != LDAP_SUCCESS)
{
  /* int errno_save = errno; */
  perror("ldap_initialize() failed"); /* This call shows the error message related to errno. */
  /* If on a GNU system also the following will do: */
  /* fprintf(stderr, ""ldap_initialize() failed with #%d: '%s'\n", errno_save, strerror(errno_save)); */

  writeDebugLog("CONNECTION Fail!.");
  writeSyslog("CONNECTION Fail!.");

  ldapErrorString = ldap_err2string(status);
  writeDebugLog("Connection to server failed with [%s].", ldapErrorString);
  writeSyslog(
    "LDAP server initalization error. Check [%s] server's status.",
    serverAddress
  );
  return(NULL);
}
```

---

**Update:**

Using the `ldap_init*()` functions does not try to establish a connection, so any invalid address data will not be detected as such. To actually test the connection use `ldap_open()`, but `ldsp_init()`.

From [man `ldap_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ldap_open.3.html):

> **ldap_init()** acts just like **ldap_open()**, but does not open a connection to the LDAP server.  The actual connection open will occur when the first operation is attempted.

Comment: I'll give your suggestion a try and see what happens. Please hold on a moment.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I seem to be having the exact same trouble. `status == LDAP_SUCCESS` even though I have deliberately set the server address to a non existing address. `ldap://123.45.67.89:9321`

Comment: You need to call `ldap_open()` to find out this address isn't valid.

Comment: Going to give that I try right now. I should call `ldap_initalize()` then `ldap_open()` like that in succession then?

Comment: It looks like just `ldap_open()` is the answer. I'll do a few more checks.

Comment: It was actually the documentation that led me to `ldap_initalize()` because it stated that `ldap_open()` was deprecated in favor of `ldap_initalize()`. That information is in the documentation as well.